# CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created

Tags: vsto, excel-2007

I'm trying to run an Excel 2007 VSTO 3.0 addin we've created.  However since installing the ION Trading MarketView Excel Plug-in our add-in no longer seems to load properly and fails with the following error:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
>
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
> at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
> at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
> at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.LoadMafPipeline(AppDomain newDomain, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, AddInInformation info, EntryPoints requestedEntryPoints, OfficeApp officeApplication, OfficeVersion officeVersion, IntPtr& executor)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?  Any pointers for how I could investigate further?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips you may find on web, in order to fix the problem:

1. Reinstall VSTOR
2. Disable other add-ins
3. [Install framework 3.5 sp1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d5aec35a-e4d7-4229-8e9e-c7b826efea8b/)
4. Fix error in the security configuration on the computer that is running the Visual Studio Tools for Office solution
5. Modify/Disable custom rule of a company's virus software, blocking the .net framework ability to create the 'shadow copy' version of the vsto .dll.
6. Turn on .NET programmability support http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2010/07/30/powerpivot-not-visibile-in-excel.aspx
7. [Move the entire solution to .NET 4.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/7cf37534-e03c-4719-b6d6-76106f6d239e)

Comment: Moving to 4.0 solved that problem... now I have to weed out the depricated Interop calls :-)